# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify() - onResponse

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to set the adapter of a RecyclerView within the onCreate(). I read that the notifyDatasetChanged()  can be invoked on the main thread only. But how can this be achieved? Here is my code so far:

```
RecyclerView recyclerViewSt;
List<GitHubstarredRepos> myDataSource = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerViewSt = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.starred_repos_recycler_view);
    recyclerViewSt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    myAdapter = new StarredReposAdapter(myDataSource, R.layout.list_item_starred_repo,
            getApplicationContext());

    recyclerViewSt.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

public void loadStarredRepos (View view){
    GitHubStarredRepoAPI apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(GitHubStarredRepoAPI.class);

    Call<List<GitHubstarredRepos>> call = apiService.getStarredRepoName(newString);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubstarredRepos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubstarredRepos>> call, Response<List<GitHubstarredRepos>>
                response) {

            myDataSource.clear();
            myDataSource.addAll(response.body());
            recyclerViewSt.notify();

    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of notifying `RecyclerView`, Notify your `Adapter`.